# Getting letters in a string. Why my code didn't work well?

Tags: java, string, char, java.util.scanner

I am new to java and I barely have the time to study it. Actually, my question is a little bit awkward and meaningless. I am trying to get letters from user input. I know that there are more efficient ways to do it, but I only want to know what is wrong with this method. The problem is when I write a string that doesn't contain any space the program is fine but if I write one with spaces it stops work.

```
Scanner qx = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = qx.next();
for(int b = 0; b<a.length();b++){
    char z = a.charAt(b);
    System.out.print(z + " ");
    }
```

For example: When I wrote `"Hi there"` (without quotes)
I expect the output of `"H i t h e r e"`
But it only shows `"H i "`
İf I would have written `"Hithere"`
it would show `"H i t h e r e "`
So why is there a difference between the one has spaces and the one doesn't?
Also, I am sorry for my grammar. I tried to do my best but I haven't practised for a long time.

Comment: change `qx.next()` to `qx.nextLine()`

Comment: for more information on the why: check this -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

Answer (score 1):

I had these same problems when started to code in java. Like reading inputs which are mixed with integer and string.

For Ex :

if you want to read...

```
5 // as an Integer
Hi there // as a string
```

you have to code like this

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = in.nextInt();
in.next();
String str = in.nextLine();
```

I put that extra  ***in.next()*** to move the buffer to the next line (as it would be only at the end of the same line after reading an integer number).

So, now coming to your question, ***next()*** will just read the bytes until the whitespace occurs. so if you want to read one full line of input you have to use ***nextLine()***. ***nextLine()*** will read the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

`next` returns any string up to a whitespace character (space, tab, enter).

You need to use `nextLine` which returns any string up to a carriage return (aka enter).

Answer (score 0):

That's how `.next()` works. It takes string until first space.
This will work for you:

```
String a;
while(qx.hasNext){
a = a + qx.next();
}
```

And then continue with your loop.

Answer (score -1):

this code will help you to extarct the exact substring from your main string

public static void main (String [] args) {

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a String");
String name = input.next();
/*from this line it will extract the charcter from the string
 * according to tour indexes given
 */
String subString = name.substring(0, 3);
System.out.println("Substring is :"+subString);

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is answering the question. You are still getting only `"hi"` if you input `"hi there"`. And the substring with constant value doesn't help if I input "hello there" or worst `"a"` ... Can you explain why you think this is useful please ?